# Where to put big, rarely used functions in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a several functions which are quite large, and are only used in one controller function each, and I'm wondering where to put these? They are not displaying any views, but instead crunching some numbers.

If I'm not wrong, there are 4 possible places where i could put these function: in my controller, in a helper, in a library or in a model. But none of these seem appropriate, since I don't want the code to be loaded every time a user uses the controller, and model should be used to do database stuff, and helpers and libraries should contain code that can be used over and over again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter comes with helpers that you probably might not use (doesn't load unless you specify it in the application/config/config.php file) and I don't think its a problem having functions that you only use once stored there (application/helpers ). For example I might use a random password generator once only, but its still there and won't be loaded unless I call it.

```
$this->load->helper('my_string_generators');
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is business logic, the best place to put it is in the controller as a private method, then you can call that method from within the controller.

Just as a note, helpers aren't always loaded unless you autoload them or load them in the constructor of your controller. So, as an alternative, you can make these methods of a helper then just load the helper in the controller action you wish to use them. That way they only get loaded when you need them.